# Rendering tabular rows with formset in django-crispy-forms

Tags: django, tabular, django-crispy-forms, formset

I want to display a list of instances as a `formset` with `django-crispy-forms` and `bootstrap` where each instance appears as a row with all of the fields arranged horizontally.

All of the examples I can find seem to render the instances with their fields laid out vertically.

I thought using:

```
helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
```

might work, but that seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 9):

This is the post that got me to a solution, and I'm providing a fuller explanation here for those just getting started with crispy forms

Forms:

```
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper, Layout
...

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3']


MyFormSet = modelformset_factory(MyModel, form=MyForm, extra=0)


class MyFormSetHelper(FormHelper):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyFormSetHelper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.layout = Layout(
            'field1',
            'field2',
            'field3'
        )
        self.template = 'bootstrap/table_inline_formset.html'
```

Views:

```
formset = MyFormSet(queryset=my_qs)
helper = MyFormSetHelper()
context = {'formset': formset, 'helper': helper}
return render(request, 'my_template.html', context)
```

Template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}

<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% crispy formset helper %}
</form>

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Was going crazy just to realize I had the wrong formset factory helper. Good answer!

Answer (score 4):

Use the template attribute on the helper (documented [here](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/crispy_tag_formsets.html)):

`helper.template = 'bootstrap/table_inline_formset.html'`

Comment: use `helper.template = 'bootstrap4/table_inline_formset.html'` if you are using bootstrap4.